# I need to create my own multi-state OneNote tag

Tags: tags, onenote

I need to create a custom OneNote tag with multiple states. What I mean is the basic checkbox has a 'checked' and 'unchecked' states. I need to create a custom tag with more states, something 'in progress' with a '.' instead of a 'check' mark and preferably a fourth state of an arrow. Any idea how I can do this or if it is even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no native way to do this, period.

There is a possible workaround, though.

Here's a tag:

```
  <one:OE creationTime="2013-10-02T09:33:28.000Z" lastModifiedTime="2013-10-11T06:30:52.000Z" objectID="{6998E7A0-D98A-47DC-818A-A7494BE7140A}{14}{B0}" alignment="left" quickStyleIndex="1">
    <one:Tag index="1" completed="false" disabled="false" creationDate="2013-10-11T06:17:32.000Z" />
    <one:T><![CDATA[Tag Text]]></one:T>
  </one:OE>
```

As you can see it's wrapped in an OE and the tag text is in a `<one:T>`'s CData. The Index is related to TagDef at the top of the page and this specifies the Symbol/TagType

What you can do is add Meta information to the surrounding OE, you can add an unlimited number of these, such as:

```
<one:Meta name="TAG_PROGRESS" content="0.8" /> // 80%
```

Things will get really funky when there's more than one tag in the outline, though.

And the rub is that OneNote won't use this information or render it in any way so you'll need either a separate app or an add-on to interact with your meta information.

There is absolutely no way you can display additional tag symbols within the page, you've just got the 143 that come as standard and the only way to define them is in the TagDef. I guess you could get creative and display extra images in the OE itself but they wouldn't be part of the tag itself. You'd need to check the [OneNote XSD](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/descapa/archive/2013/08/07/onenote-2013-com-api-xml-schema-onenote-2013-xsd.aspx) to see how to legally add those extra images.